# Round to the next tenth, subtract 0.02

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird-3.0

I have an ITEMS table with a PRICE column. I added 4% to the price using the built-in functions in the application, but that leaves the result not in a friendly formats for retail. I want all the prices to end with 8 (so $24.93 becomes $24.98)

I need to replace the PRICE with a PRICE rounded to the next 10th, and then subtract .02. This would make 24.93 becomes 25 then subtract .02, making it 24.98.

Could someone help with crafting a SQL query to do this?

Perhaps something like `UPDATE ITEMS SET PRICE=(ROUND (PRICE,2)-.02)` ?

Comment: What does `24.90` become?

Comment: @Bohemian 24.9 rounds to 24.9, - 0.2 = 24.88

Comment: which is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to always round up, you should use [`ceil`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref30/fblangref30-functions-math.html#fblangref30-scalarfuncs-ceil), not round. Note that `ceil` doesn't have a precision argument, so you'll have to implement this yourself by multiplying the price by 10, ceiling it, and then dividing it back by 10:

```sql
UPDATE items SET price = CEIL(price * 10) / 10 - 0.02
```

If you're anxious to actually do this, you could query this expression to verify it gives the correct result before actually applying the update:

```sql
SELECT price, CEIL(price * 10) / 10 - 0.02 AS corrected_price
FROM   items
```

Comment: mysql's ceil doesn't take a second parameter (unlike round, which does), so you need to do `ceil(price*100)/100`

Comment: it's actually interbase SQL (Firebird 3)

Comment: @johncastaldi so please edit your question and remove the mysql tag. Anyway, the Firebird also has a similar [`ceil`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-scalarfuncs-ceil) function, so the answer still stands

Comment: You need to multiply and divide by 10, not 100, to achieve the desired result.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel good catch, thanks. Got the second decimal place of 0.02 stuck in my head... :-( [edited and fixed]